# Why is SELECT COUNT (*) returning 1

Tags: android, sqlite

Why is my `getAccountCount` only returning 1 when there are multiple entries in my database. Is this not the proper way to get the number of entries in my `ACCOUNTS` table?

**getAccountCount**

```
int getAccountCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + ACCOUNTS, null);
    int x = cur.getCount();
    cur.close();
    return x;
}
```

**Calling it from another activity**

```
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    txtNo.setText(String.valueOf(dbHelper.getAccountCount()));
```

**Slightly embarrassed with my slip-up so here's an attempt to recover a little dignity ;_;.**

In any case apologies for my mistake and thank you for the help. I'm fiddling with a tutorial code which had `SELECT * FROM myTable` originally but I read somewhere that using `SELECT *` in a large db could potentially affect performance as `SELECT *` gives the list of records with all columns from the table whereas `SELECT COUNT *` just counts the rows. But when I replaced `SELECT * FROM myTable` with `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM myTable` I forgot to change the interpretation of `cur` and just continued under the assumption that my `getAccountCount()` was fine.

Again, thank you for the help and criticism, both are appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: and without braces around the asterisk?

Comment: FSM save us! ... how many rows with count is returning this query? ... 1 ... so what's you expected ... you have to take the value from first row not count of rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my getAccountCount only returning 1 when there are multiple
>   entries in my database

Because `Cursor.getCount()` return number for rows in current cursor instead of count value.

To get `COUNT` value from cursor use `Cursor.getInt` with `0` position :

```
cur.moveToFirst();
int x = mcursor.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return nomber of entries in table

```
int numRows =(int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want getCount().
Even if the result of Select COUNT (*) is 5, getCOunt() will be 1...

you should rather do something like

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) // data?
   System.out.println(cursor.getInt(0);
```